# BroadcastReceiver to send notification and update ui if activity, active

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have an activity which just displays a daily counter. When the day ends, i want to send a notification with last day counter, insert it in a db and if the app is running update the counters label to zero.

I think i must register a static `<receiver>android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED</receiver>`. so as to get notified even if the activity is not running.
There I insert the value in DB and i send the notification.

And a dynamic created broadcast receiver which i will unregister onPause, which receives the same events, but it will only update the UI and specifically the label.

Is this the best solution?

Is there any way from a `broadcastReceiver` to make my `Activity` (if is running) to go to resume again ?
Is it possible from `broadcastReceiver` to call a `Service`, which will update my UI if my Activity is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more reading i found that the best solution is the above.

A static broadcast receiver for DATE_CHANGED actions. This will start a Service which will update the db and send a local custom broadcast (com.myBroadcast.WakeUpActivity)
The Activity if is running will register a receiver for the previous custom broadcast (will unregister onPause), and will update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Use broadcastreceiver that would catch the event

```
public class EventReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                NotificationService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

broadcastreceiver give event service

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {

    private final ServiceBinder binder = new ServiceBinder();
    private ServiceListener serviceListener;

    public NotificationService() {
        super("NotificationService");
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        serviceListener = null;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //send notification
        if(serviceListener != null){
            serviceListener.updateActivity();
        }
    }

    public void setServiceListener(ServiceListener serviceListener) {
        this.serviceListener = serviceListener;
    }

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public NotificationService getSevice(){
            return NotificationService.this;
        }
    }

    public static interface ServiceListener{
        public void updateActivity();
    }
}
```

then you need to connect to the service in your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements NotificationService.ServiceListener {
    private boolean isBound;
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            NotificationService.ServiceBinder binder = ((NotificationService.ServiceBinder)service);
            binder.getSevice().setServiceListener(MainActivity.this);
            isBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(!isBound) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
            bindService(intent, serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(isBound){
          unbindService(serviceConnection);
          isBound = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateActivity() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //update you list here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and do not forget to mention the service and broadcastreceiver in the manifest file and specify the intent filter

```
<receiver android:name="EventReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="........." /> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="NotificationService"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a [LocalBroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to send events to your Activity , a working example could be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Antarix/8131277)

Comment: but i cant receive broadcast evens while my application is not running.

Comment: when app is in background you don't need to update the UI , simply update your value in DB silently in static BroadcastReceiver

Comment: so you suggest to do what i am writing in my post:
1) static broadcastReceiver to update DB
2) dynamic to update my UI, but if i want to listen for events such as date_change i must register it in Context not locally

Comment: Simply the flow could be listening for date change event in static BroadcastReceiver(where you will update DB) for some Intent Action defined in manifest and register the same Intent Action for LocalBroadcastReceiver(where you will update UI) in Activity. Let me know if you face some problem.