# How to update UI from notification service

Tags: android

I am getting message through push notification, i want to get it and show in LIST view . is there anyway to do this ?

in a notification i am getting message and username . so i want to show that message in list view .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839606/broadcastreceiver-to-send-notification-and-update-ui-if-activity-active/27840360#27840360

Comment: Only in your case, the method updateActivity(); has to be with the parameters updateActivity(String name, String message);

Answer (score 0):

When You implement push notification u have to extend a abstract class **GCMBaseIntentService**.

This class has a method name

```
 @Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Received message");

    try {
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");// This is the message u sent via push notification...same u can do for username
        Intent i = new Intent(context, "Your Activity name");
        generateNotification(context, i, title, message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```